# MacOS Mojave - LaunchAgent plist doesn't run for all users

Tags: macos, parallels, launchd, macos-mojave

I have a plist that I've placed in /Library/LaunchAgents which is designed to, for all users, run a script which launches Parallels. (As I'm running an environment with network users, I don't have the luxury of simply setting it as a launch item.) The launchd is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encodings="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
      <key>Label</key>
      <string>com.parallels.autostart.agent</string>
      <key>Program</key>
      <string>/Library/Extras/OpenWindows.sh</string>
      <key>RunAtLoad</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So, as you can see it's fairly standard as far as a launchd goes. However, it only runs for the user who created it, and not for any other users. Even checking through launchctl, it isn't listed as something which is running or has run. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `ls -l@eO /Library/Extras/OpenWindows.sh`? (that's lowercase ell, at-sign, lowercase e, capital Oh) I want to make sure that script is executable by everyone. Oh, and do the same `ls -l@eO` of the plist itself.

Comment: @Spiff Output for the fist is ```-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 macuser  staff  - 40 May  3 14:08 /Library/Extras/OpenWindows.sh
 com.apple.TextEncoding 15 
 com.apple.lastuseddate#PS 16 
 com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags 42 
 com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_xnj4uz5xaefxw3hwfenpaf7jk4 89``` Output for the second is ```-rw-r--r--@ 1 macuser  staff  - 381 Apr 26 15:10 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.parallels.autostart.plist
 com.apple.TextEncoding  15 
 com.apple.lastuseddate#PS  16 
 com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags  42 
 com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_xnj4uz5xaefxw3hwfenpaf7jk4  89 ```